# self.transitionToRoute('default'); does not execute code in window.App.DefaultRoute and show blank page

Tags: ember.js, routes

Thanks for any pointer or help.  I have a self.transitionToRoute('default'); in a controller code.  It is being called after creating a new object.  It transition to default.index as printed out in the console.  However, it shows blank page and not the original default page coming in.  Also, I have a console.log statement in the DefaultRoute's model: function(params).  I only see it being call the first time coming in but not with the transitionToRoute.  Is there anything to configure when changing route programmatically?  Also, when I click around and execute the {{#link-to 'default'}} after moving away from the blank page, the DefaultRoute's model: function(params) is executed.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you provide a simple fiddle ???

Comment: Thanks Selva.  Turns out I just had to provide explicit DefaultIndexRoute and DefaultIndexController to specify the path to execute the code I had.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your DefaultRoute is one with a dynamic segment isn't it?

Have you read this note in the doc?

> Note: A route with a dynamic segment will only have its model hook
>   called when it is entered via the URL. If the route is entered through
>   a transition (e.g. when using the link-to Handlebars helper), then a
>   model context is already provided and the hook is not executed. Routes
>   without dynamic segments will always execute the model hook.

Maybe you need to provide a model as second argument...

```
self.transitionToRoute('default',model);
```